# Solr. Store not the original field, but filtered one

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing

I am trying to index Wikipedia's dump. In order to provide abstract for the articles (or, maybe, enable highlighting feature in future) I'd like to store their text without WikiMarkup. For the first try, it would be enough for me to leave just alphanumeric symbols. So the question is it possible to store the field, that is filtered at character level, not the original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this out of the box. If you want Solr to do this, you can create your own [UpdateHandler](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/update/UpdateHandler.html), but this might be a little tricky. The easiest way to do this would be to pre-process the document before sending it to Solr.

Comment: I've already came up with the same conclusion. That's what I'll probably implement, if there'll be enough time. Thanks anyway, and I appreciate the hint on UpdateHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Solr by default stores original field values before the filters are been applied by the index time analyzers for your fieldType. So by default it is not storing the filtered value. However you have two options for getting the result that you want.

1. You can apply the same filters to the field at query time as are being applied at index time to remove the wiki markup. Please see [Analyzers, Tokenizers and Token Filters on the Solr Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters) for more details.
2. You can apply the filters to the data in a separate process prior to loading the data into Solr, then Solr will store the filtered values, since you will be passing them in already in a  filtered state.

Comment: I accepted jpountz's answer because of the useful hint on implementing custom UpdateHandler. And I see you suggestion No.1 to be of no use for my purposes as I don't see any point in making user to build queries using WikiMarkup.

Comment: No worries. However, you are missing the point of No. 1. The users do not need to write queries with WikiMarkup. In your Solr fieldType that is storing the wiki page text, if you strip the WikiMarkup while indexing using something like the PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory, you need to also use that same filter on the query side of the fieldType definition. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers for more details.